# Powershell script to open another script as admin

Tags: admin, administrator

I have a script that I can double click and it'll open other scripts as admin.  Works with some things but not everything.  For one script, it opens the next window and then immediately closes it.  For another, I get this error:

At MYPATH\InstallClient.ps1:33 char:78
+ ... tall_x64.msi" -force -recurse -ErrorAction Stop #Cleans out the file  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
At MYPATH\InstallClient.ps1:27 char:31
+ ForEach ($entry in $computers){ #start of foreach loop
+                               ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Below is the script to open a script as an admin:

```html
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
$OpenFileDialog.filter = "PS1 (*.ps1)| *.ps1"
$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$OpenFileDialog.filename
}
$inputfile = Get-FileName "MYPATH\Scripts"
powershell.exe -noprofile -command "&{start-process powershell -ArgumentList '-NoExit -noprofile -file $inputfile' -verb RunAs}"
```

This is the script that it gives the previous error for while trying to open:

```html
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory) #Function to choose a file
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
    
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = "MSI (*.msi)| *.msi" #type of files that will be available for selection
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
}
$inputfile = Get-FileName "MyPath" #Directory that is going to open to select a file from

Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory) #Function to choose a file
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
    
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv" #type of files that will be available for selection
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
}
$inputfile1 = Get-FileName "MyPath\ServerLists"
$computers = import-csv $inputfile1

ForEach ($entry in $computers){ #start of foreach loop
$computername = $entry.computernames #this saves the single entry under computernames for each entry in csv file
Copy-item $inputfile -container -recurse \\$computername\C$\windows\temp #this copies the msi file that we selected to the computer entry called from the csv file's temp folder
Invoke-Command -Computername $computername –ScriptBlock {Start-process -Wait "C:\windows\temp\ShadowSuiteClientInstall_x64.msi"} | out-null #This starts the msi file that we just copied and waits for the installation to be completed before moving on
If($?){ #If the last command was successful
Echo "Installed ShadowSuiteClientInstall_x64 on $computername."
Remove-Item "\\$computername\C$\windows\temp\ShadowSuiteClientInstall_x64.msi" -force -recurse -ErrorAction Stop #Cleans out the file we copied into the temp folder
}
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why this will open some things fine but give this error for this script and immediately close other scripts without running them?  Does anyone have a better way to navigate through scripts and select one to open as admin?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out.  I loaded the script into powershell ISE and I saw that it was compiling it incorrectly.  It kept turning the -Scriptblock into an ae symbol instead of the - in front of scriptblock.  Weird AF IMO but ok, I fixed it in ISE, which I recommend to anyone struggling with weird compiling errors like this.